# toggle div animation

Tags: javascript, html

trying to make this animation work, so only one of the content5 divs is open at a time, currently there are 3 heading5 divs and three content 5 divs.  If you click one of the heading5 links to "open" the content5 child, then the other content5 children should close of they are open.  I know this should be easy, but I can't seem to pull it off, I keep learning so much of this out of order.  need to watch more Crockford.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content5").hide();
  $(".heading5").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".content5").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
  });
});
```

here is the html

```
<div class="heading5 menu-item-text" id="leftend">About</div>
<div class="content5 clearfix" id="menu-1">
  //Links in here
</div>
<div class="heading5 menu-item-text"><a href"#" data-target="2">Contact</a></div>
<div class="content5 clearfix"  id="menu-2">
      //More links in here
</div>
<div class="heading5 menu-item-text" data-target="3"><a href"#">Portfolio</a></div>
<div class="content5 nav clearfix" id="menu-3"  data-option-key="filter">
//and more in here
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkuhns/NRsXS/

I realize the dangers of sliding a menu open width wise as it may get cutoff, but I have different menus styled for different screen sizes, so I should be OK.  In the fiddle please ignore the horrible mouseover effect, I am fighting a css style in query mobile that I haven't defeated yet, so for the moment I put in the mouseover until I get it.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: can you share your html code ?

Comment: Please provide fiddle content since code and explaination you have provided is not enough

Comment: added both, a shortened version of the html and the fiddle with lots of my ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

Right before the line

`$(this).next(".content5").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 'slow');`

Add

`$('.content5').animate({width: 0}, 'slow')`

Edit: Updated code in fiddle: jsfiddle.net/fNZaV/2

Comment: When I first saw this I thought I was all set, makes perfect sense, animate all widths to 0, and the toggle the desired one, but it doesn't, I must have something wrong with the floats in the css. I even tried separating out all the pieces and calling them by id.

Comment: @jkuhns5 if the animation doesn't work, try setting the content elements' `overflow` to `hidden`. If it still doesn't work, see if it works when you animate a different property instead of `width`, say `display` which you then toggle between `inline-block` and `none`.

Comment: Still no dice, doesn't seem to matter what property I animate, from what I can tell stuff is happening, but the content div is moving the next header div over like it did before.  Gonna scrounge and see what else I can find....  I try changing the float setting, but that is even worse.

Comment: adding display:table to the contents made it better, it now functions, but still doesn't toggle.

Comment: Got it closer, by calling the individual elements by id and using hide instead of animate, but unfortunately hide doesn't go from left to right to complete the effect.

Comment: So I'm looking at your fiddle, what exactly do you want the menu to do? Is it a simple droipdown menu, or is your desired effect more complicated? A picture would be nice. The code is really convoluted, are you generating it with dreamweaver or something?

Comment: @ eighttrackmind Nope not dreamweaver, though thats pretty funny.  That bad huh.  I am just teaching myself javascript, jquery and css3 now.  I haven't even touched html in many many years, and of course I am going feet first, out of order, without the basics.  Check out http://www.meridianprinting.com/cerf  I have the menu going there, it is close and functions but the 'hide' effect isn't what I am going for, I want it to pinch back closed like they do when they open.  Thanks.

Comment: @jkuhns5 sorry about the delayed response, work's been busy. Anyway, I cleaned up your HTML and CSS and made them more semantic (so the menu will still be readable and functional with CSS/JS disabled), and improved your animation performance. Take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/NRsXS/14/

Comment: whoops, looks like that's the old one. here's the fixed link - http://jsfiddle.net/q7JhD/

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you.   Most of it I get and makes sense to me, though I don't know if I could yet write it on my own.  Its gonna take me a while to pick apart and understand.  I would like to figure out why you can't collapse the currently open child by clicking its parent again.  How do I give you credit?  upvote the above answer?  Thanks again. I'll keep messing with the fiddle.

Comment: Glad to help! When I was learning this stuff the community helped me a lot, and I want to return the favor :)

Comment: No need to give me credit. Here's an updated version where sections are collapsible - http://jsfiddle.net/fNZaV/2/. The reason they weren't in the last version is because if you look in `showSection()`, the value that 'padding-right` animates to is always the same, and doesn't toggle between `0` and that value. That's the part that's updated in the new version. Let me know if there's anything else that doesn't make sense - there are lots of ins and out of why I did things a certain way.